# undefined is not an object react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having a problem with setting a state to data from fetch API response

```
render() {
    function getCode(text) {
      fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "telephone": text, 
          "password": "123123"
        })
      }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(this.state.text)
        console.log(this.state.uid)

        this.setState({uid : response["data"]["telephone"]})
        console.log(this.state.uid)
      // this.setState({uid: response["data"]["telephone"]})
      // console.log(this.state.uid); 
    })
  }
```

here is my constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      text: '',
      uid: ''
   }
}
```

So I am just sending a request, and need to save response inside of the state, but instead, I am getting an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this2.state.text')]

Code lines which is commented are my attempts to fix it.

UPD 1:
here is response from APi

```
{"data":{"telephone":["Some data"]}}
```

Comment: Could you include your entire component? Having the `getCode` function in the render method looks a bit odd.

Comment: I guess you might not have "data" or "telephone" in your response

Comment: @somsgod where it is referring to? And how to make to refer to this class?

Comment: let me see response data structure. log it

Comment: Before getCode function try var that  = this; And inside response use that.setState. But as arrow function is used this should have worked. But you can still try this.

Comment: you should fetch before component will mounting ...  use lifecycle method  componentDidMount

Comment: @Tholle there are 100+ lines, not sure if i can post it here, I mean stackoverflow rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declare that function when component did mount inside render function

```
 class Something extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        text: '',
        uid: ''
      }
  }

   getCode = (text) => {
      fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "telephone": text, 
          "password": "123123"
        })
      }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(this.state.text)
        console.log(this.state.uid)

        this.setState({uid : response.data.telephone})
        console.log(this.state.uid)
      // this.setState({uid: response["data"]["telephone"]})
      // console.log(this.state.uid); 
      })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      //...you can call it this.getCode(/..../)
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues is that you are creating a function within a method and `this` within a function doesn't refer to the `this` in your method.

```
render() {
  function getCode(text) {
    // `this` in here is not the React component
  }
}
```

Here's a simple example:

```js
class Example {
  method() {
    // `this` within a method (invoked via `.`) points to the class instance
    console.log(`method=${this}`);
   
    function functionInAMethod() {
      // because functionInAMethod is just a regular function and
      // the body of an ES6 class is in strict-mode by default
      // `this` will be undefined
      console.log(`functionInAMethod=${this}`);
    }
    
    functionInAMethod();
  }
}

new Example().method();
```

You can just extract `getCode` as another class method and call `this.getCode()` when needed.

```
getCode() {
  // ...
}

render() {
  this.getCode();
}
```

Other options are to:

1. [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the `this` of `getCode` when creating the function
2. use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call) or [`apply][3]` to set the `this` when invoking the function
3. use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for `getCode` to [preserve the `this` across nested functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)
4. bind the `this` into a variable in `render` and use that variable within `getCode` instead of `this`

**⚠ Note**: You don't want to make http requests in the `render` method because it is called quite frequently, consider doing it in a less brittle manner. The usual pattern is to do it in the constructor or `componentDidMount`.